# Monotouch: UIDocumentInteractionController, view documents (pdf, word, excel and so on) How to?

Tags: file-io, xamarin.ios, uidocumentinteraction

I have a question for you and I don't know to resolve it. I'll try to explain this scenario.

1) My iPad app connects to a web server and can download documents.
2) Once downloaded, it can open the document.

My questions are:

first, is it possible to download a stream (or something else) in the ipad? Do I have to save it as a temporany file?

second, how can I use the UIDocumentInteractionController to open that downloaded file?

Thank you in advance. Regards.

**EDIT:**

How it is possible to change the title for buttons of the preview document? By default, there is a button whose title is "Done". Is it possible to change its title or replace it with another one?

The code I'm using is the following:

```
public class UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateClass: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

public UIViewController FileViewController;
 public UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateClass (UIViewController parent)
 {
   FileController = parent;
 }

 public override UIViewController ViewControllerForPreview (UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
 {
   return FileViewController;    
 }

 public override UIView ViewForPreview (UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
 {
  return FileViewController.View;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get ready for some reading. :)

You can find the answer to the first question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application). Answer to the second question [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403).